# How to get Visual Studio project to output to approot/bin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution for my Azure cloud service.  The solution has a MVC site in one project and a windows service in another project.  I would like to run the windows service at startup on the web service.

I get an error that the service is not found in approot/bin.

How do I get the Windows Service project to install itself in approot/bin when I build locally or deploy to Azure?

Comment: A web application should be run by a non-privileged user who has no business to start, let alone install system-wide services. What goal are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far that gives you an error?

Comment: The web role starts fine.  To my csdef for the web worker role I added a Startup command that installs my service on the web worker's vm (which I am using to take the web application online and offline).  The error is the service is not found in approot/bin